# Proximity Beacon Api project for Android is not scanning for devices

Tags: api, proximity, google-nearby

I am trying to implement Proximity Beacon Api for Android.
I downloaded the project from 
https://github.com/google/beacon-platform/tree/master/samples/android
I can successfully run the project and after clicking on SCAN button in app nothing gets displayed.
 I converted one of my Android device into EDDYSTONE beacon by installing app from
https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid.

But still did not find any luck in scanning beacons.

I also had a doubt that, where should I use **clientID** generated in google developer console.

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try Nearby Messages API?
https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages

Comment: How does using Nearby Messages API fix the Proximity Beacon sample project?